# Unable to set result of Fetch call to a variable and the Promise doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch-api

I have past experience with Promises and Fetch calls in JavaScript but I just can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to fetch data from a site and store a part of the header as shown below:

---

```
async function getData() {
    
    let response = await fetch("url.....", requestOptions);
      
    let data = await response.headers.get('set-cookie') 
      
    return data;
  }
  
async function main() 
{
    const dataset = await getData();
    console.log(dataset) // This here prints out the data AFTER everything has ran, makes sense as it probably waits for the promise to be resolved.
    data = dataset // This does not set the value of data to dataset. It sets it to Promise <Pending> 
  }
  
main();
```

---

So from here how can I finally set the variable Data to the resolved promise? I thought the 'await getData()' would wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing, thus allowing data to be set to an actual value and not a promise.

Comment: Where is the `data` defined that you are assigning to in `main`, and where are you attempting to use it?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me, Seem issue with `console.log`

[console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

```
async function getData() {
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/");
  let data = await response.headers.get('content-length') 
  return data;
}

async function main() 
{
  const dataset = await getData();
  console.log(dataset) // This here prints out the data AFTER everything has ran, makes sense as it probably waits for the promise to be resolved.
  data = dataset // This does not set the value of data to dataset. It sets it to Promise <Pending> 
  console.log(data)
}

main();
```

Comment: Ive noticed that when I call console.log(data) it doesn't tell a true story of when the variable it set. I get a false impression that data is set to a value but when I call it elsewhere I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to `await` main.

I'm guessing you're doing something like this

```
main() //call to main
console.log(data) //call to see `global` var data set
```

You need to do something like this

```
await main()
console.log(data)
```

If you're calling `main` from top level, you may not be able to add `await` so you need to declare an inline `async` method and call it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but I am still facing the same problem. It feels like I'm just going in circles constantly adding another layer of async/await... console.log(data) prints out the correct data but only at the end of the whole output. By this time the rest of the program has ran with 'data' being undefined...